# ASP.NET Core App Doesn't Run On Localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to run an `ASP.NET Core` with `Angular`. Though was able to configure the `Angular` project, unfortunately the `ASP.NET Core` project run successfully but getting the followings in the browser:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
```

Let me write I've run the project successfully in another PC with the same configuration for the current one. Both has the same core version - 2.2. I am not sure why I am getting the above but would expect some ideas to get it resolved.

**Startup.cs**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        #region MyRegion
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.UseRowNumberForPaging()));

        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        // configure jwt authentication
        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });


        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);       
        services.AddTransient<ISchemeMaster, SchemeMasterConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IPlanMaster, PlanMasterConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IPeriodMaster, PeriodMasterConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IRole, RoleConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IMemberRegistration, MemberRegistrationConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IUsers, UsersConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IUsersInRoles, UsersInRolesConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IPaymentDetails, PaymentDetailsConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IRenewal, RenewalConcrete>();
        services.AddTransient<IReports, ReportsMaster>();
        services.AddTransient<IGenerateRecepit, GenerateRecepitConcrete>();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(implementationFactory =>
        {
            var actionContext = implementationFactory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
            return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
        });
        #endregion

        // Start Registering and Initializing AutoMapper

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
        services.AddAutoMapper();

        // End Registering and Initializing AutoMapper

        services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilterAttribute)); })            
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)      
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
        });
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .WithExposedHeaders("X-Pagination"));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "6XJCIEJO41PQZNWJC4RR"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "Data Source=.;Database=SampleDB;"
  }
}
```

**Update**: It was version 2.2. Skipped that part initially.

Comment: Did you try to change the default log level to get more info ?

Comment: How are you running the app locally? In Visual Studio or via the CLI? In the former case you can check the Output window (Show output from ASP.NET Core Web Server). In the latter case, the output will be directly in the console window you're running in. In either case, check that output for exceptions being thrown on startup and resolve accordingly.

Comment: Or maybe the port already in use?

Comment: I've already changed the port @Baruch but that didn't help.

Comment: No actually @agua from mars. Though not that familar with that, but trying t learn it using this link - https://jonhilton.net/2016/09/21/log-different-levels-in-asp-net-core-app. Would appreciate if you could suggest if this is fine to follow or anything else.

Comment: For the `AP.NET Core` app, I am using **Visual Studio** and same for `Angular` @Chris Pratt. Basically the projects are in different location - Two different project files.

Comment: I meant your appsettings.json Logging:LogLevel:Default = "Warning", just set it with "Debug"

Comment: You probably have an Angular compilation issue, try to compile your SPA with angular cli : `ng build` in the SPA directory

Comment: 502.5 is specifically a failure to start your ASP.NET Core app, likely due to an exception being thrown during startup. We need to see that exception, so check your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly matter to resolve. Though let me write if anyone faces this issue, just check the error log or output window to see the required tools or `.NET Core` version. In my case, I forgot to install the `.NET Core 2.2` and here is the link below:

[.NET Core 2.2 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.2.103-windows-x64-installer)

Thanks to everyone who commented to sort this out.